# Image is fetched from firebase storage but src value is unable to set in react ANTD Avatar component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am using Avatar antd component. My image is fetched from the Firebase storage.

Here is the code which I already implemented.

```
  test = (imageName) => {
    if (imageName)
    {
        firebaseConfig.storage().ref().child(`users/${imageName}`).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            return url;
        })
    }
    else{
        return "https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png";
    }
}
```

Here imagename will be considered as child name as you can see in the code.

Now, I will show you How I call that function from the class component.

```
 <Avatar src={this.test(imagename)} />
```

It is working fine if imagename is null.

Would you please help me to do so as I am new for React and Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when `imageName` is not null, you use a promise to fetch the url from firebase. This means that an asynchronous operation will start (calling firebase for the url), and when it finishes the function you passed to the `then` will be called with the url that was found.

The problem is that returning from inside the promise doesn't return it from the function (since the function already returns while the asynchronous operation goes on in the background.

The solution in react for this problem would be to use state to store the url, and update it from within the `then` when the promise resolves.

In that case you will call the `test` function on the component mount, and instead of returning the url, it will set it to the `state`.

```
test = (imageName) => {
    if (imageName)
    {
        firebaseConfig.storage().ref().child(`users/${imageName}`).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            this.setState({imageUrl: url});
        })
    }
    else{
       this.setState({imageUrl: "https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png"});
    }
}
```

Then you can use it from the `state` like this:

```
 <Avatar src={this.state.imageUrl} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I will save the URL into state then how can I access it in "src" attribute.

Comment: You should do something like `<Avatar src={this.state.imageUrl} />`

Comment: Then From where I will call the function to set the value into imageUrl?

Comment: I added some code to my answer which should help you understand what I mean.